# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to bean.Book

Tags: java, jsp

I want to use bean in a JSP page with an arrayList.
Here is the servlet code :

```
public class ResServlet extends HttpServlet{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn");
    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String author = request.getParameter("author");
    String publisher = request.getParameter("publisher");
    String year = request.getParameter("year");
    ArrayList<Book> book = JDBC.getBooks(Integer.valueOf(isbn), title, author, publisher, Integer.valueOf(year));
    request.setAttribute("book", book);
    System.out.println("Class ResServlet :\t ISBN : " + isbn + "| title : " + title + " | author : " + author + " | publisher " + publisher + " | year : " + year );

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("book.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

One I have initialized my arrayList, I make a redirection to a JSP page named "book.jsp". This JSP page contains this piece of code :

```
<jsp:useBean id="book" class="bean.Book" scope="request"/>
<c:forEach items="${book}" var="b">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${b.title}"/></td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

When I run my application, I have got that stacktrace from book.jsp :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to bean.Book
    org.apache.jsp.book_jsp._jspService(book_jsp.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    servlet.ResServlet.doGet(ResServlet.java:29)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<jsp:useBean id="book" class="bean.Book" scope="request"/>` tells the JSP that in the request scope you are passing a `bean.Book` instance under the name of `book`. The servlet compiler will actually create Java code that will cast the resulting object to the declared class.

However you are passing a `java.util.ArrayList`, which is not assignable to a `bean.Book`.

Define your book (or should it be *books*) as `<jsp:useBean id="book" class="java.util.Collection" scope="request"/>` The most general form of an `ArrayList` is a `Collection`.

```
<jsp:useBean id="books" class="java.util.Collection" scope="request"/>
<c:forEach items="${books}" var="book">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${book.title}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it shows me an error when I modify the class attribute :
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Cannot instantiate the type Collection
 - Collection is a raw type. References to generic type Collection<E> should be 
  parameterized
EDIT : finally I changed Collection to ArrayList

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="books" class="java.util.Collection<?>" scope="request"/>

Comment: I have tried this solution. With java.util.ArrayList warnings have disappeared. But I have nothing displayed on the JSP  page.

Comment: Make sure you put the right bean in the request scope with the correct contents. Either the list is empty or it is not put in the scope (although I think that would result in a runtime error).

Comment: Thank you ! I have forgotten to change "book" to "books" on my servlet (request.setAttribute("books", book)).